# Custom route in Sails Js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

How to write custom route for subfolders inside sails application.
I disabled the blueprints for overriding [waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) ORM with [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/), after creating a folder inside the controller i added the following code in route.js

```
module.exports.routes = { 'post v2/my/create': 'v2/MyController.create' };
```

After doing all these i tried to call the API but it shows 404 Not Found Error

Answer (score 2):

in route.js add the path as follows

```
module.exports.routes = { 'post /v2/my/create': 'v2/MyController.create' };
```

Answer (score 2):

**Your route fails because the path lacks a preceding forward slash**.  [From the docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes):

> Note the initial / in the path--all paths should start with one in
>   order to work properly.

Assuming your controller is located at `/api/controllers/v2/MyController.js`, your controller path [should be correct](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/controllers/routing-to-controllers):

> For controller files saved in subfolders, the subfolder is part of the controller identity:

`'/do/homework': 'stuff/things/HomeworkController.do'`

Interestingly, it seems that even lifting with silly logging enabled, a failed route path does not trigger any log event.  Perhaps this is a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug (paths without preceding slashes can be used for internal routing) but it might be good to have it throw out a warning.

Comment: @sgress454 can you elaborate a little?  Possibly I'm not understanding what you mean by 'internal routing' - does this refer to the [sails router](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/master/lib/router) as compared to the express router?

Comment: Either.  You can emit a `request` event on the Express router or virtual (Sails) router (see https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-hook-subapps/blob/master/index.js) or even just change the `req.url` in a policy and call `next('route')`.  In any of these cases, a route without a preceding slash is perfectly valid.  But it's used very infrequently.